# Is there a notation for "exists but not necessarily unique"?

Tags: soft-question, notation

Somes it is useful to write "there exists not necessarily unique value such that..."

For instance, for any convex function $f$, there exists a (not necessarily unique) global minimizer $x$.

Since "there exists a unique" is written as $\exists !$, is it possible to write something like $\exists \not!$.

Is there a standard notation for this?

Comment: Is $\exists$ not good enough?

Comment: @JonatanB.Bastos Yes, it is enough, but sometimes you really would like to emphasize that the existence of a certain object is not necessarily unique

Comment: The emphasis is part of the meaning of $\exists$. If someone doesn't understand this, the problem isn't lack of expressiveness by the symbol $\exists$, but rather the person in question not understanding what $\exists$ means.

Comment: There is no common way in logic to denote that you aren't assuming something.  What that would even mean isn't unambiguous.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The phrase is simply "there exists", notated $\exists$.

In *English*, if you wanted to emphasize that you don't mean "there exists a unique ...", then you might say "there exists at least one ...".

Symbolically, there should be no need for this emphasis.

Comment: I think you mean "there exists at least two..." to emphasize that it's not unique. Small typo.

Comment: @Krish: "I'm not saying that it's unique" is different from "I am saying that it's not unique". The OP and my answer are talking about the former.

Comment: +1 for distinguishing between using English and symbols. You can always explain things in words rather than symbols, and doing so is generally clearer and more expressive.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider emphasizing the possible non-uniqueness in a footnote. It doesn't make the text heavier (only by the size of your footnote indicator) and you can even afford a small comment regarding why this is important to you.